# persian character regex with english and persian number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have a regex pattern for validating persian characters:

```
/^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/
```

but it doesn't accept number.
i don't know how to edit this.
i want this pattern accept english and perisan/farsi numbers.

thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pattern already seems to cover Persian numbers, so if all it is missing is English numerals, you may simply add them to the regex character class:

```
/^[\u0600-\u06FF\s0-9]+$/
```

[See here](http://sartre2.byu.edu/persian/persianword/numbers.htm) for a chart of Unicode symbols for Persian numbers.

Comment: i have another pattern /^\d+$/ to check if string contains only digits. how can i add persian number to it? i want this to accept english and persian number to check if this string contains only digit or not. thanks

Comment: Try `/^[0-9\u06F0-\u06F9]+$/` ... under the assumption that `\u06F0-\u06F9` covers the range of Persian numbers.

Comment: but it seems it does't cover this: 02156736250٧٧٧٧

Comment: @M0RT3Z4 Careful...that character you used is actually an _Arabic_ number 7 (`\u0667`), not a Persian number 7 (`\u06F7`).  If you read the chart I linked to, you will see this warning as well.